# Instagram relationship API doesn't work

Tags: instagram-api

Hi I'm developing my App by using Instagram API.

When I use relationship API, I got a 404 status Error.

Does not relationship API work??

My request url and parameter is

url : https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token={myAccess token}
parameter : action // follow

the method of http is post

Is there anybody has experience like this?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem..

the problem was that I sent wrong user-id in url.

I sent real Instagram user id that is login id.

but the user-id to be used in the url has to be "id" which is returned by other APIs..

If you have problem like this , and If you need futher more information about it.

please comment.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get information about a user by using the 'real Instagram' nickname you can use:
https://www.instagram.com/NICKNAME/media/